# Text on Hover Image padding

Tags: css, squarespace

I successfully added css code to our squarespace site to make gallery images have the title of each image appear on hover. The problem is that the title leaves extra white space (about 15px) bellow each image. I want each image to be touching each other on top and bottom the same way they do on the sides.

My code is bellow, here is the link to the page: https://baikart.com/artists2

I've tried using padding code but that pushes the image around and I just want the white space gone.

```
.summary-content {
    position: absolute;
    color:#fff;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#Main-content {
    .summary-content {
        position: absolute;
        color:#fff;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all .5s ease;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    }
}

.summary-item:hover {
    img {
        -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
        filter: brightness(50%);
        transition: all .5s ease;
    }

    .summary-content{
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The links each of those images are wrapped in have a margin-bottom of 15px, assigned via selector `.sqs-block-summary-v2 .summary-block-setting-show-title .summary-thumbnail-container`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Fade in Overlay</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/07/56/money-2696229_960_720.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope the solution will help

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS, inserted via the CSS Editor, will remove the gap between images:

```
#collection-5d1bb9f4d43d220001cae017 .summary-thumbnail-container.sqs-gallery-image-container {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

The CSS targets the "Artists 2" collection specifically by using its collection ID, which is an `id` attribute set on the `body` element. That way, if you create a different collection that you want to format differently, it will be unaffected by the CSS. If you want to apply the style globally, remove the `#collection-....` ID selector at the beginning and simply target via classes. It also means that, if you want to target a different collection (but without applying the styles globally), you'll need to update the collection ID in the selector above.